# Regular expression for matching the same words in the text

Tags: regex

For example, I have text:

The **word1** **word2** is **word3**
*(note word1 can be == word2 == word3)*

I want my regular expression work when distance between words **word**(*i*) <= **N**. Distance is the number of words between words **word**.

The distance between word1 and word2 id 0.

The distance between word2 and word3 is 1.

The distance between the word1 and word3 (=2) should not be taken into account.

I make regular expression to solve this problem, but it takes into account the distance between the first and the last same words. How can I fix it?

```
(\b\w+\b)\W+((\b\w+\b)\W+){N,}?\1
```

For my text example I want regular expression which will be find matches, only when N=0 or 1.

```
(\b\w+\b)\W+((\b\w+\b)\W+){0,}?\1
(\b\w+\b)\W+((\b\w+\b)\W+){1,}?\1
```

But now it works also when N=2

```
(\b\w+\b)\W+((\b\w+\b)\W+){2,}?\1
```

Comment: What is your definition of  *distance*?

Comment: Your statement of the problem is quite confusing.  Please give some examples of acceptable and non-acceptable inputs that illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: @revo The number of words between same words.

Comment: What should be the expected output for `N = 1` in your given example?

Comment: I emphasis on *what should be the expected **output***.